# Why filtered out rows in between is selected but not being deleted?

Tags: excel, office-js

Can someone help me with a issue when "shift + left click" selection on a filtered table and how it interacts with row deletions?

Steps:

1. Setup sample table
2. filter the table
3. register the selection changed event
4. shift + left click on two rows with discontinuous row number, selection change handler return  all rows which included filtered out rows
5. right-click on the selections above and "delete sheet rows", filtered out rows were not being deleted.

Question:

- Should the filtered-out rows in between be selected?
- Should the filtered-out rows in between be deleted?

My code snippet:

```js
$("#setup").click(() => tryCatch(setup));
$("#register-on-selection-changed-handler").click(() =>
tryCatch(registerOnSelectionChangedHandler));
async function registerOnSelectionChangedHandler() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let table = context.workbook.tables.getItemAt(0);
    table.onSelectionChanged.add(onSelectionChange);
    await context.sync();
    console.log("A handler has been registered for table onSelectionChanged event");
  });
}
async function onSelectionChange(args) {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    console.log("Handler for table onSelectionChanged event has been triggered. The new selection is: " + args.address);
  });
}
async function setup() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    context.workbook.worksheets.getItemOrNullObject("Sample").delete();
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.add("Sample");
    let salesTable = sheet.tables.add("A1:E1", true);
    salesTable.name = "SalesTable";
    salesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Product", "Qtr1", "Qtr2", "Qtr3", "Qtr4"]];
    salesTable.rows.add(null, [
      ["Frames", 5000, 7000, 6544, 4377],
      ["Saddles", 400, 323, 276, 651],
      ["Brake levers", 5000, 8766, 8456, 9812],
      ["Chains", 5000, 1088, 692, 853],
      ["Mirrors", 225, 600, 923, 544],
      ["Spokes", 5000, 7634, 4589, 8765]
    ]);
    sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
    sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
    sheet.activate();
    await context.sync();
  });
}
/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your questions!

**The answers are:**

> Should the filtered-out rows in between be selected?

Yes, these filtered-out rows **will be** selected.

> Should the filtered-out rows in between be deleted?

No, these filtered-out rows **will not be** deleted.

I understand your confuse, but this is a by-design behavior.

A common knowledge is: "Shift-click lets you select a range of elements and ctrl-click lets you toggle the selection of single elements in the set." The filtered-out cells are just hidden in the UI, so when user shift-click two rows all other rows between the twos are also selected, and the onSelectionChanged handler will return contiguous cells.

For the deletion, when user right click the selections and delete cells, the delete action only affects the selected cells within the visible range. So the filtered-out cells will not be deleted.